# Spring Security: logout, lock, or disable user by name

Tags: spring-security

I have a test app that is using spring security that has 3 users [suzy, frank, julie]. My application sends events to an external security analysis system. That system analyzes the events to determine if it's an "attack" and the application then polls that system to see if any of the events have been deemed to need a response. Here's an example:

1. bob performs action 1 (event sent)
2. bob performs (bad) 2 (event sent)
3. bob performs action 3 (event sent)
4. application polls external system and finds that bob should now be logged out
5. bob gets logged out (HOW ?)
6. bob's next request gets redirected to the login page

A few notes:

- The external analysis system is checking things that spring security would not check (think fraud analysis or something like that)
- The "polling" check is essentially a background thread, so it's not blocking requests

I essentially would like whatever action I'm taking to have effect on the next request from bob. I would like something like:

```
loadUserByUsername("bob").disable();
```

The capabilities I'm looking to build right now are just:

- logout
- disable

I can do logout by caching the user session and then invalidating it, though I'd prefer a better way (ie. `loadByUsername("bob").logout()`). I can't figure out how to perform an account disable though.

My hope is to NOT have to build custom implementations of the core apis if possible. I'd like this to be something where anyone using spring security can integrate this functionality easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will break this down into your two questions:

## Logging Users Out Programmatically

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to do this without extending the core APIs in some way. Fortunately, integrating with the core APIs is rather trivial.

I'm outlining a few approaches for this because I am not certain the "background approach" is providing much advantage (more on this later).

### Custom SecurityContextRepository

At this time, I think this is the best approach.

A background thread approach (as requested) makes sense so you do not have to block when making requests to your application. However, you cannot easily communicate with another thread (let alone another process on another computer in the instance of a clustered environment) without some shared data store.

The way Spring Security obtains the current user is using a `SecurityContextRepository` implementation. The default implementation obtains the user from the `HttpSession`. What you can do is something like this:

```java
public class SecurityAnalyzerSecurityContextRepository 
      implements SecurityContextRepository {

    private final SecurityAnalyzer securityAnalayzer;

    private final SecurityContextRepository delegate;

    public SecurityAnalyzerSecurityContextRepository(SecurityAnalyzer securityAnalyzer) {
        this(securityAnalyzer, new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository());
    }

    public SecurityAnalyzerSecurityContextRepository(SecurityAnalyzer securityAnalayzer, SecurityContextRepository delegate) {
        this.securityAnalayzer = securityAnalyzer;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public SecurityContext loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder requestResponseHolder) {
        SecurityContext context = delegate.loadContext(requestResponseHolder);
        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        if(authentication == null) {
            return context;
        }
        String principal = authentication.getName();

        // your SecurityAnalyzer implementation would need implement isEvil
        if(securityAnalyzer.isEvil(principal)) {
            return SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        }
        return context;
    }

    public void saveContext(SecurityContext context, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        delegate.saveContext(context, request, response);
    }

    public boolean containsContext(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return delegate.containsContext(request);
    }
}
```

The idea is that you can delegate to an existing `SecurityContextRepository` and validate that the user has not been determined to be evil.

Alternatively, you could provide a `SecurityContextRepository` implementation that loads from a store that the background thread can write to. Either way though there is a blocking call to the store.

### Background Thread Approach

**NOTE**: I don't think this is the correct approach and thus this answer is not as detailed.

The first step is to write the background task that polls your external system. Obviously this step cannot be provided by Spring Security, because it does not know how to interact with the external system.

The code for this might look something like:

```java
SecurityAnalyzer analyzer = ...
Set<String> evilUsernames = analyzer.getAndRemoveNewEvilUsernames();
... what to do with evilUsernames? ...
```

The question now becomes what to do with the evilUsernames. By default Spring Security will obtain the current user from `HttpSession`. Most Servlet Containers default the `HttpSession` implementation to persist to an in memory `Map`. Spring Security has no way of obtaining a reference to this `Map`.

#### Using JSESSIONID directly

One option is if we are able to obtain the JSESSIONID for each of the users we could make a request like this:

```
GET /j_spring_security_logout HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: JSESSIONID=<some-id>;
```

This becomes a bit more difficult if CSRF protection is enabled. To get that to work you would need to expose the `CsrfToken` as an endpoint and make a call to obtain it first:

```
GET /csrf HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: JSESSIONID=<some-id>;
```

Then using the response you can make a POST with the token:

```
POST /logout HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: JSESSIONID=<some-id>;

_csrf=<csrf-token>
```

At this point you might ask, but how do I know the JSESSIONID? One option is to use Spring Security's [concurrency control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions). However, the out of the box implementations do not work for a clustered implementation.

Ultimately, the information would need to be passed into the SecurityAnalyzer and returned from the SecurityAnalyzer or a custom Spring Security API is going to be necessary.

#### Spring Session

Once Spring Session adds support for [querying sessions by a user identifier](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/7), you would be able to invalidate sessions by the username.

Alternatively, if SecurityAnalyzer knows the session ids then Spring Session would work now.

## Locking Accounts

You were also needing to know how to lock an account. Spring Security provides a mechanism to support locking accounts.

You can use a `UserDetailsManager` implementation to update the `UserDetails` to return false for `isAccountNonLocked`. Then Spring Security's `DaoAuthenticationProvider` will leverage `preAuthenticationChecks` which ensures that the account is not locked.

If you have written your own `UserDetailsService`, then the built in `UserDetailsManager` implementations will not work so you will need to update your user model so that the custom `UserDetailsService` creates a `UserDetailsService` that returns false for `isAccountNonLocked`.

Comment: As promised, wanted to give an update. This worked perfectly. The only piece I had to add was `.and().securityContext()    .securityContextRepository(myCustomSecurityContextRepository).and()`when configuring the `HttpSecurity` object.

Thanks for the incredibly helpful response.