# Locking accounts through EventListener base on user record in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My question is similar to
[How can I limit login attempts in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351391/how-can-i-limit-login-attempts-in-spring-security)
The problem is after following a recent high voted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35294221/1278112

Following code is my approach.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationEventListener.class);

    Set<RequestLimitRule> rules = Collections.singleton(RequestLimitRule.of(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 3)); // 3 request per 10 minute, per key
    RequestRateLimiter limiter = new InMemorySlidingWindowRequestRateLimiter(rules);

    @EventListener
    public void authenticationSuccess(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        String username = (String) event.getAuthentication().getName();
        if (!limiter.overLimitWhenIncremented(username)) {
            limiter.resetLimit(username);
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void authenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
        String username = (String) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        boolean reachLimit = limiter.overLimitWhenIncremented(username);

        if (reachLimit) {
            User user = (User) userDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(username);
            //User is security.core.userdetails.User
            user = (User) User.builder().username(user.getUsername()).accountExpired(!user.isAccountNonExpired())
                    .accountLocked(true).disabled(!user.isEnabled()).password(user.getPassword())
                    .authorities(user.getAuthorities()).build();
            userDetailsManager.updateUser(user);
        }
    }
}
```

It would throw `UserNameNotFoundException` instead of `LockedException`, found `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` is @Autowired by default, assuming it doesn't have the user information.

Since the users information is stored in the DB, the `JdbcUserDetailsManager` was tried to replace `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`, but it would allow login attempt after fails over limiter.
After checking the source code of [JdbcUserDetailsManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.java), I found out the `updateUser()` in it wouldn't track the `AccountNonLock` property.

The answer from @Ron Winch on [Spring Security: logout, lock, or disable user by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725829/spring-security-logout-lock-or-disable-user-by-name)

> You were also needing to know how to lock an account. Spring Security
>   provides a mechanism to support locking accounts.
>
> You can use a UserDetailsManager implementation to update the
>   UserDetails to return false for isAccountNonLocked. Then Spring
>   Security's DaoAuthenticationProvider will leverage
>   preAuthenticationChecks which ensures that the account is not locked.
>
> If you have written your own UserDetailsService, then the built in
>   UserDetailsManager implementations will not work so you will need to
>   update your user model so that the custom UserDetailsService creates a
>   UserDetailsService that returns false for isAccountNonLocked.

So a custom `UserDetailsManager` implementation to update the `UserDetails` is used. It would change the record DB. But again it does nothing when fails over limiter.

After searching, the answer in 
[Spring Security : LockedException is thrown instead of BadCredentialsException, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969890/spring-security-lockedexception-is-thrown-instead-of-badcredentialsexception) point out

> DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks: check for locked...

After reach [spring security reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-dao-provider) found out there is a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

Do I have to config somehow to make it work with the custom `UserDetailsManager`?
Or is there other better path to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Ron Winch is quite right

> You can use a UserDetailsManager implementation to update the
>   UserDetails to return false for isAccountNonLocked. Then Spring
>   Security's DaoAuthenticationProvider will leverage
>   preAuthenticationChecks which ensures that the account is not locked.

However the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` and the `JdbcUserDetailsManager` is not suitable for me.

So I implement the `UserDetailsService` instead of `UserDetailsManager`

> If you have written your own UserDetailsService, then the built in
>   UserDetailsManager implementations will not work so you will need to
>   update your user model so that the custom UserDetailsService creates a
>   UserDetailsService that returns false for isAccountNonLocked.

And inject it to `AuthenticationManager` through `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());

    ....
}
```

related part of UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    ....

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        //the custom implemetation
    }
}
```